# How do you JavaScript style area elements on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, area

I've got an image map with 20 area elements, only four shown below. I want to style each area so that a blue border appears whenever a user hovers over it - all the area shapes are rectangles.

```
<map id="mymap" name="mymap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,223,221" href="http://..." />
    <area shape="rect" coords="226,0,448,221" href="http://..." />
    <area shape="rect" coords="451,0,673,223" href="http://..." />
    <area shape="rect" coords="677,0,1122,223" href="http://..." />
    ...
</map>
```

I've tried using CSS to style each area, but it's not working. And I've tried to put an `onmouseover=color()` on the map element and call the following function, but that doesn't seem to be working either:

```
function color() {
    var blueboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('area');
    for(var i=0; i<blueboxes.length; i++) {
        blueboxes[i].style.border = 'solid blue 5px';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/) can be used for this.

> Mapper.js 2.4 allows you to add automatic area highlighting to image maps on your webpages (inc. export to SVG).
> It works in all the major browsers - Mozilla Firefox 1.5+, Opera 9+, Safari and IE6+. On older browsers, it can use ["jsgraphics" from Walter Zorn](http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm#download) (if installed), else it'll degrade and your visitors won't notice a thing.

### Sample code from that website:

> Please note that everything below this line is his code and wording, not mine. Full attribution belongs to the link above.

**Setting Up**

Download mapper.js and include it into your webpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wz_jsgraphics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mapper.js"></script>
```

"wz_jsgraphics.js" is copyright by Walter Zorn and not part of the distribution!

**Using It**

To get the highlighting just add a class="mapper" to an div surrounded image.

```
<div>
<img src="..." class="mapper" usemap="..." alt="...">
</div>
```

To get individual area highlightings add one or more classes to the area.

```
<map>
...
<area shape="poly" class="noborder icolor00ff00" href="#" coords="...">
...
</map>
```

To get multiple area selections add one or more id's to the areas rel attribute.

```
<map>
...
<area shape="poly" id="blue" rel="green,red" href="#" coords="...">
<area shape="poly" id="green" rel="red,blue" href="#" coords="...">
<area shape="poly" id="red" rel="green,blue" href="#" coords="...">
...
</map>
```

To force a group of areas using the attributes of the initial area.

```
<map>
...
<area shape="rect" id="black" class="icolor000000 forcegroup" rel="green,red,blue" href="#" coords="...">
...
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

The area tag can't be styled like a normal anchor. I would use a different approach. You could apply your image to a div as the background-image and then position clickable elements over the div by using position: absolute.

Take a look at this technique: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssmaps/

Answer (score 0):

Can [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) helps?

Have a look at [this sample](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html) :)

Comment: How will that help someone trying to use an image map? Raphaël is an SVG library.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the approach I see is to build the imagemap itself out of different images in CSS.  Here's a good example of this:

http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/examples/europe-map.html

Comment: Yeah, but I think he's trying to retrofit the concept onto an existing imagemap solution. I would prefer to see something done in CSS myself too. That's how Bing does it, after all.

Comment: Yeah, I really wanna avoid going through splicing all these 20 different areas up into images. Looking for a JS solution, the one below is pretty awesome.